# Tables aren't scrollable in jQuery Mobile on a narrow screen

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've got a mobile website with a bunch of links and tables inside them.

I used jQuery Mobile for the whole thing. Here's what the outline looks like:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="" table_1>
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Timetable for MSc Programmes</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <table>
      <--! the large table is here -->

    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Unfortunately this is what the page looks like on my phone. The full table can't be seen and isn't scrollable, so visitors can only view part of the table unless they switch into landscape mode.

[image: Phone screenshot]

Enclosed a table into a div element and gave it the 'webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;' and 'overflow:scroll;' tags.

It added the scroll bars, but the width is still not represented accurately:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the table inside a container div and give that div a CSS class. Then setup the CSS class to scroll:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div class="tableCont">
        <table>
           <--! the large table is here -->

        </table>
   </div>
</div>

.tableCont {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

-webkit-overflow-scrolling allows mobile webkit to scroll individual dom elements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately all it did is add scroll bars, the width is still wrong and part of it is hidden. I edited the main post to show

Comment: @slava, maybe change overflow to auto. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y0oLj2vy/